# Smarty Tag Library in Dreamweaver CS5

Tags: smarty, dreamweaver, color-scheme, flash-cs5

I have begun working with the Smarty template framework at a new job, something completely new and bewildering to start off with but my previous knowledge of PHP defiantly helped.

I am finding that using Smarty in Dreamweaver CS5 is looking a little bland and have yet to find a way to colour code the smarty tags.

I have been given a Windows 8 PC to work on which may mean that some of the extensions i have found online don't work.

Does anyone know of a way to add these tags into DW and colour code them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried any of these two:

```
http://smartydwt.klitsche.org/
```

and

```
https://code.google.com/p/dreamweaver-smarty/
```

These work but they don't work for me becasue I don't want to change the smarty syntax.  The first one makes smarty tags instead of `{if $x}` into `<smart:if $x>` (if I remember correctly it has been years since I used it, this was originally made for Macromedia Dreamweaver 2004 or so). And the second one turns it into `{{if $x}}`

If you just want syntax highlighter/code-coloring look into this:

```
http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=ConfiguringDreamweaver
```

Comment: Thanks @Neo, i have since moved over to Sublime but that link to Google looked like the perfect solution! There are quite a few Macromedia Dreamweaver solutions but noting more up to date, that must be saying something about Smarty ;)

Comment: I think it's saying more about Dreamweaver, Smarty is a great template engine, there are many other things that are not available for Dreamweaver, Smarty is not the only one. I have not yet been able to find a good plugin for LESS syntax highlighting, Coffee Script, etc... (though I have CS5 and not 6)